# Back button causes iFrame to delay window.onLoad event

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, iframe, jquery-events

I serve ads through an iFrame. The ad network's servers are much slower than mine, so I asyncronously load the iFrame on the `window.onload` event.

```
// (using Prototype library)
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
  $('ad').writeAttribute('src', '/ad.html');
  // other initialization here
});
```

A problem occurs when you enter the site via the browser's back button. Unexpectedly, the ad iFrame attempts to load immediately (before the load listener above sets the 'src' attribute), delaying the `load` event for a few seconds. During these few seconds, the site is unusable because I do a bunch of initialization in window.onload.

As far as I know, this only happens in Firefox. How do I prevent this blocking load?

Comment: Go to www.veetle.com for an example of this happening. Notice the register and login buttons in the upper right? They are inserted on window.onload. It's quickly done when you first load the homepage. Try clicking any other page and clicking back to the homepage. You'll see how the register and login buttons don't show up until the horrendously slow ad iFrame is loaded.

Comment: thanks for the URL! It made it much easier to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Theory

The issue you've noticed could be described like this: an iframe in a document loads the URL loaded in it at the moment the outer page was navigated from, not the URL specified in the outer page's HTML source (or an empty page in your case).

The fact that it delays `onload` is just a corollary: the load event is delayed until all the resources (images, frames, etc) are finished loading.

I couldn't find documentation explaining that it should happen this way, nor any bug reports acknowledging it as a known issue, but FWIW I see exactly the same behavior with Google Chrome 10.0.612.3 on the testcase below.

This behavior, even though unintuitive in your case, has some logic behind it: document loads in frames historically are recorded in the session history (back/forward navigation history). Suppose you open a site, that has its main content in a frame, and navigate the inner iframe. After going away from the site, then returning via the back button, the browser should arguably load the last loaded page in the frame.

### Solutions

Surprisingly, this doesn't appear to be a common question, so these suggestions are based on my understanding of the issue, I haven't tested them in any scenario more real than the testcase below.

1. The best experience for the user would be if you made the [bfcache](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching) work. As far as I can see, this would require the ad document be cacheable (using different URLs to show different ads, instead) and possibly changes to the JS framework you use (if it happens to always break bfcache, I don't know, this used to be a problem with other frameworks).
   If you pulled this off though, there would be no `load` event at all, the page would just be restored exactly in the state it was left in, and it would much snappier than anything that hits the network.
2. The only way to prevent the iframe from loading the URL from session history I can think of is to avoid having the iframe in the HTML source. If you insert it dynamically, it wouldn't be the "same" iframe the next time the page loads, so it would default to the URL you specify in its src.
3. Instead of trying to prevent the iframe from loading the ad on 'back', you could make your code currently running off the `load` event not be blocked by the iframe. For this you could use the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events#DOMContentLoaded) event.

### Appendix: Testcase

```
<iframe id="a"></iframe>
<pre id="b"></pre>
<script>
var b = document.getElementById("b")
b.innerHTML += "before 'load': iframe src=" + document.getElementById("a").src + "\n";
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var newURL = "https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe";
  b.innerHTML += "onload: iframe src=" + document.getElementById("a").src + "\n";
  b.innerHTML += "setting src to " + newURL + "\n";
  document.getElementById("a").src = newURL;
  b.innerHTML += "now iframe src=" + document.getElementById("a").src + "\n";
}, false);

// disable bfcache
window.onunload = function() {}
</script>
```

Comment: I will try this out when I get back to work on Monday. So let me get this straight: First I will try to not have the iFrame code in the URL. Rather, I will insert the iFrame dynamically with JS. Then I will try to use the DOMContentLoaded event rather than the plain onload event. I did some reading on this event and it seems much better than the plain onload event I've been using, because all I really need is the HTML structure to be there before I do my fancy JS; I don't need to images and such to be loaded.

Comment: I switched from the loaded event to dom:loaded event as you suggested and this fixed my iFrame blockage issue. As a side effect, it's made my JS boot up super fast on the rest of my pages because I don't have to wait for images and frames to load anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably Firefox's [bfcache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_firefox_1.5_caching) (back/forward cache), which keeps pages loaded for quicker navigation using the back and forward buttons. You can disable it for your page by binding an unload handler.

Comment: As suggested by another thread on Stackoverflow pertaining to bfcache, I attached a window.unload listener to override the bfcache. Although the bfcache was disabled, the iFrame on my page still continued to block the window.onLoad event.

Comment: @JoJo: this can't be right. Are you saying that with bfcache off the iframe attempts to load the page not specified in the HTML source before you add it in your 'load' listener? Have a testcase? // On the other hand, you shouldn't get onload at all if your page is in bfcache (cf. your original question), so you're not telling us something.

Comment: I'm not even certain how to tell if bfcache was disabled or not. I was told that attaching any unload handler would disable it. I did an Event.observe(window, 'unload', function(){alert('unloaded');}). I did indeed see the alert box popup when I left the page. Then when clicked back onto the page, the ad iFrame blocked my onload event. I could tell because I saw the crappy ad agency's image ads tear in slowly and once the entire image loaded, all my onload code started running.

Comment: Right, it's not bfcache. I posted my own answer, which I believe to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Worth trying is to delay the writeAttribute until the rest of the Event is processed:

```
Event.observe(
 window,
 'load',
 function() {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $('ad').writeAttribute('ad.html');
  }, 0);
 }
);
```

This will execute as soon as *everything else* is done.

Comment: I thought doing a setTimeout with 0 just makes the code execute in another "thread" / asynchronously. What do you mean by it executing after everything is done? I tried your suggestion, but it did not work. The iFrame still blocked onload. I could see the stupid ad agency's code load 100 files (too stupid to use minify) in Firefox's status bar as I waited 10 seconds for onload to run my code.

Comment: No, Javascript only has one thread.  The function given to setTimeout will not be executed until the current function (and all the functions calling it) return. But since it doesn't help in your case, see my next attempt at an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Worth trying is to delay the writeAttribute until the rest of the Event is processed:

```
Event.observe(
 window,
 'load',
 function() {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $('ad').writeAttribute('ad.html');
  }, 0);
 }
);
```

This will execute as soon as *everything else* is done.

**Huh, SO won't let me put in two answers**

I don't know why this is happening but you try putting *another* iframe between your page and the ad: your page loads an iframe; that iframe waits a few seconds (letting your page load), then loads the ad, which will take up the entire area of the intermediate iframe.

Comment: I have a high traffic site, so adding an extra HTTP request will burden the servers. I wish for a client-side only solution. Thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: Don't serve the intermediate page from the your site.  It's just HTML and Javascript.  Serve it from the same CDN that serves your images, CSS, and Javascript (which you better have, or else don't be talking to me about your "high traffic" problems).